# How to make test with OpenJPA Maven Plugin

Tags: java, spring, maven, integration-testing, openjpa

I need to make an integration test for check multithread-persist into Oracle. We use openjpa in our application so I decide to use [openjpa-maven-plugin](http://people.apache.org/~mikedd/openjpa/openjpa-maven-plugin/sql-mojo.html) to make that test.

I've tried to prepare some profile to test

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>integration-test</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.openjpa</groupId>
                    <artifactId>openjpa-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${openjpa.version}</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <sqlAction>build</sqlAction>
                        <sqlFile>/src/test/resources/sql/insert.sql</sqlFile>
                        <connectionDriverName>org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource</connectionDriverName>
                        <connectionProperties>
                            driverClass=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver,
                            jdbc.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@server-test-ora:1521/bacl,
                            user=user,
                            password=root,
                            minPoolSize=5,
                            acquireRetryAttempts=3,
                            maxPoolSize=20
                        </connectionProperties>
                        <includes>**/entities/*.class</includes>
                        <addDefaultConstructor>true</addDefaultConstructor>
                       <enforcePropertyRestrictions>true</enforcePropertyRestrictions>
                    </configuration>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>test enhancer</id>
                            <phase>process-test-classes</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>test-enhance</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>

                    <dependencies>
                        <dependency>
                            <groupId>org.apache.openjpa</groupId>
                            <artifactId>openjpa</artifactId>
                            <version>${openjpa.version}</version>
                        </dependency>
                    </dependencies>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

But actually, I don't understand what I need to do and How to make that test. How to get EntityManager to try to execute my insert.sql

```
INSERT INTO USER (NAME,SURNAME,DATE) VALUES ('NAME','SURNAME',to_date('2018-12-08 17:21:03', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'));
```

What I need It's trying to make some concurrent test. I have a lot of that but without any DB and now I need test connection or inMemoryOracle.

So my question is
How to get EntityManager from the plugin ( Does it need to create any context.xml else?)